# Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $\ker T=\ker T^2$ and $\text{Im}T=\text{Im}T^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $\ker T=\ker T^2$ and $\text{Im}T=\text{Im}T^2.$ Prove that $V=\ker T\oplus \text{Im}T.$

My Attempt: We first show that $\ker T\cap \text{Im}T=\{0\}.$ In order to do this we pick $x\in \ker T$ and so we have that $T(x)=0$ and also $\exists y$ such that $T(y)=x.$ Thus $T^2(y)=0$ and since $\ker T^2\subset \ker T$ we have that $y\in \ker T$ which implies that $T(y)=x=0.$ Thus the intersection is $0.$ Now we have to show that $V=\ker T+\text{Im}T.$ Clearly $\ker T+\text{Im}T\subset V.$ And so we show the the other inclusion. Let $v\in V.$ Then $v=v-T(v)+T(v).$ We will show that $v-T(v)\in \ker T$ as $T(v-T(v))=T(v)-T^2(v)=0.$ And $T(v)\in \text{Im}T$ be definition. So $v\in \ker T+\text{Im} T.$ and thus we have that $V=\ker T+\text{Im}T.$

I wanted to know whether this solution is correct or not since I am self-studying and there are no solutions provided at the back of the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument that $T(v)-T^2(v)=0$ is not correct. The fact that $T(V)=T^2(V)$ does not imply that $T(v)=T^2(v)$ for all $v\in V$. You could instead argue as below: there exists $w\in V$ such that $T(v)=T^2(w)$. Then you can express $v$ as $v=v-T(w)+T(w)$. Now prove that $v-T(w)\in \ker T$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not right. Why do you assert that $T(v)-T^2(v)=0$? This doesn't follow from the fact that $\operatorname{Im}T=\operatorname{Im}T^2$.